# Voltage drop from a logic gate?

Tags: circuit-analysis, schematics, logic-gates

In the following schematic with a logic-AND gate:

[image]

I would expect that since the inputs are logic-high of 5V for both input A and input B, that the output would also be logic high at 5V, yet it looks like the output is about 0.45V (since `V=IR`, `V=0.455*1`). Why is the voltage here that number and not 5V or something close to that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A real gate would not be able to supply anything like 455mA. You've loaded the output with far too low a resistance. Try something more like 100K or 10K.

They've probably added a placeholder 10\$\Omega\$ resistance internally just to prevent infinite current if you short the output in the simulation. A real gate would be more like 100\$\Omega\$ (though it does not behave exactly like a constant value resistor when the output voltage drop gets higher than a fraction of a volt).